# Como fazer função onkeypress em campo dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Tenho uma tela de pesquisa onde existem várias checkboxs que, quando selecionadas, exibem os campos gerados dinamicamente. Gostaria de colocar uma função "onkeypress" para que, quando o botão enter seja pressionado a função de pesquisa seja realizada.

O problema central é: Não consigo fazer com que o setAtribute do campo gerado insira a função que eu criei. Abaixo segue o código:

Função que faz a pesquisa:

```
 function enter(e)
 {
     var unicode =e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
     if(unicode == 13)
     {
        pesquisa();
     }
 }
```

OnKeyPress que deveria entrar no campo dinâmico:

```
onkeypress="enter(event)"
```

E aqui é onde o campo é gerado dinamicamente:

```
if(document.getElementById(sID).checked == true)
{
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var input = new Array();
    var p    = new Array();
    var tr  = new Array();
    var td  = new Array();

    var camada = document.getElementById("campos");

    p[cont]     = document.createElement("p");
    tr[cont]    = document.createElement("tr");
    td[cont]    = document.createElement("td");
    input[cont] = document.createElement("input");

    table.border = 0;
    table.width  = "350px";
    table.id     = 'tbl_'+sID;
    td[cont].height = "35px";

    input[cont].id   = 'inp_'+sID;
    input[cont].name = 'inp_'+sID;
    input[cont].type = 'text';
    input[cont].setAttribute("style","width:500px;");

    var label = document.createTextNode(sValue+':');

    p[cont].appendChild(label);
    td[cont].appendChild(p[cont]);
    td[cont].appendChild(input[cont]);
    tr[cont].appendChild(td[cont]);
    table.appendChild(tr[cont]);
    camada.appendChild(table);
    cont++;
}
```

Comment: pensou em `input[cont].addEventListener("keypress", enter)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
input[cont].onkeypress = enter;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j36fhrgj/)**</kbd>

Ou então com [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
input[cont].addEventListener("keypress", enter);
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j36fhrgj/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Assim funcionou, muito obrigado!